# spark-How can I retrieve item-pair after calculating similarity using RowMatrix

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have encountered the "all-pairs similarity" problem in my recommendation system. Thanks to [this databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html), it seems RowMatrix may come to help.

However, RowMatrix is a matrix type without meaningful row indices, thereby I don't know how to retrieve the similarity result after invoking `columnSimilarities(threshold)` for **specific item i and j**

Below is some details about what I am doing:

1) My data file comes from [Movielens](http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) with format like this:

```
user::item::rating
```

2) I build up a RowMatrix in which each *sparse vector i* represents the ratings of all users to this *item i*

```
val dataPath = ...
val ratings: RDD[Rating] = sc.textFile(dataPath).map(_.split("::") match { 
  case Array(user, item, rate) => Rating(user.toInt, item.toInt, rate.toDouble)
})
val rows = ratings.map(rating=>(rating.product, (rating.user, rating.rating)))
  .groupByKey()
  .map(p => Vectors.sparse(userAmount, p._2.map(r=>(r._1-1, r._2)).toSeq))

val mat = new RowMatrix(rows)

val similarities = mat.columnSimilarities(0.5)
```

Now I get a CoordinateMatrix `similarities`. How can I get the similarity of specific *item i and j*? Although it can be used to retrieve a `RDD[MatrixEntry]`, I am not sure whether the *row i and column j* correspond to *item i and j*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem as you and solved it as follows.

1. you should note that columnSimilarities() is to call the similarity of column vectors. However, our "rows" is always composed of row vectors. So you should get the transpose of the "rows", let's suppose that is "tran_rows". Then calculate tran_rows.columnSimilarities()
2. thing is easy then. In the result of columnSimilarities(), **the index i and j** exactly correspond to item i and item j.

Comment: A caveat is that columnSimilarities() returns an upper triangular CoordinateMatrix, so only one of (i,j) or (j,i) exists in the entries. Which one exists depends on whether i < j.

Comment: How did you transpose the matrix? RowMatrix doesn't seem to have that method.

Comment: @shubhamgoel27 you'll have to convert your RowMatrix to a CoordinateMatrix and call .transpose() on that.

Answer (score 2):

If threshold is not so desirable in your case, you can use columnSimilarities on IndexedRowMatrix. That works for me very well. In this way, you have a better way to manage the row indices.

Answer (score 1):

The RowMatrix can calculate similarity between columns. So that you have to reconsider your approach to build `ratings.map(rating=>(rating.user, (rating.product, rating.rating))).groupByKey()`
(and following lines accordingly)

Then you will have ids of products in columns and you can invoke `columnSimilarities().entries` to retrieve `product-from,product-to,score` structure.

If you have large values in product id you will probably need to map your values on artificial index values. E.g. if you have 3 products with ids: 1, 900000, 9000000 then you need to map it on 0,1,2 then calculate similarities. Without this mapping you will calculate similarities between products 0-9000000 even if you don't have so many.